# HTML Email Outlook dark mode issue

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, darkmode

I created a new HTML Email template and tested outlook, I find a small issue. just change the dark mood outlook bg color change is automatically generated.
I search good and find a solution using [this link](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/). but not working.
[see the output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giu0u.png).
see my code:

```
https://textdoc.co/DEGhpsMk8Z2nzQtb
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook clients (on Windows, macOS, iOS, Android and Outlook.com) will automatically adjust your colors into a dark mode and force them to be WCAG compliant and have a 4.5:1 contrast ratio.

A solution to maintain your `background-color` if you absolutely must is to use a `background-image` of a single pixel of the color you need. (This won’t work in Outlook on Windows because it doesn’t support `background-image`.)

Comment: Any other ways?

Comment: No that I can think of (or not simpler than this any way).